# Masonry Javascript plugin causes page earthquake

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-masonry

If you look at the title in this codepen you will see that when the cards are loaded into the page, the title shakes/gets displaced. This also happens to the search bar when I am not using codepen and causes the glyph search addon to become unattached in Internet Explorer.

https://codepen.io/cryptodescriptor/pen/MQBWLL

**Search Box**

```
<!-- search column -->
<div class="col-12">
    <div class="input-group search-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
        <i style="line-height: 50%;" aria-hidden="true">?</i>
        </span>
        <label class="sr-only" for="search"></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control typeahead" id="search" placeholder="Search Coin">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Title**

```
<h1 id="page_title"><a href="">Crypto Descriptor</a></h1>
```

Forgot to mention, it happens to the footer text usually aswell.

Comment: i don't see any shaking in ff or chrome, i like your description though

Comment: It is more of a displacement. The title starts slightly to the right and moves left. I'm glad you like the descriptions though :)